# Text continuing on the same page even though the text exceeds the page

Tags: positioning, page-breaking, text, page

My question is concerning the text when the text exceeds 1 single page, it will simply not jump to the next page - instead, it is continuing on the same page and at some point, I can not see remaining text that exceeds the page.

I think the code concerning this might be this.

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{12.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

[image]

Comment: A tabular will not be able to automatically continue on a sacond page. You will need longtable instead.

Comment: Hi there!  Can you please help us more by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that replicates your problem (without sharing your personal data)?
My first guess is that the CV class you are using (if it is already made) is based on longtable or something like that.
LaTeX cannot split across pages text that is in a row/cell. The same point made by @leandriis.
It is very likely that you have to manually adjust the content of your cv entries to allow for a correct page breaking.

Comment: What is A MWE and How do I perform MWE

Comment: Change the definition of entrylist to `\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{longtable}`  and see if that works.

Comment: It worked - ty so much

Comment: @Sveinung -- That looks like an answer.  Please add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) instead of `tabular*` in the definition of `\entrylist` you will have page breaks. However, be aware that [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) breaks the pages between rows, so you may end up with large, white space at the bottom of the page. If an `\entrylist` is more than a page long, [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) will not help you.

If white space and long entries create problems, you may try to use nested `list` environments instead. This will require a total redefinition of your commands.

Here is an MWE that works using [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{longtable}
}

%\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{12.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\textcolor{lightgray}{ #3}}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}

\begin{document}


\begin{entrylist}
\entry{2020-01-02}{Kandidat -- Byggeteknologi}{Some text}{\emph{Danmarks tekniske universitet}\par\lipsum[2]\begin{itemize}
\item Item one
\item Item two
\item Item three
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]}
\end{entrylist}

\begin{entrylist}
\entry{2019-03-04}{Legal Counsel}{Some text}{\emph{Big listed company}\par\lipsum[1]}
\end{entrylist}

\begin{entrylist}
\entry{2018-03-04}{General Counsel}{Some text}{\emph{Big listed company}\par\lipsum[3]}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]